# _set.all() not working in Django Template returning AttributeError

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add the no. of comments related to a post in my Django Project. but I keep receiving a `'Post' object has no attribute 'comment_set'` AttributeError for some reason I don't understand why.

My project has a Post Model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    ----------------------------------------

    # To know how many comments
    def num_comments(self):
        return self.comment_set.all().count() <--------- Error from here

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="commented_users")
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="commented_posts")
    content = models.TextField(max_length=160)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Here is sthe views.py

```
class UserOnlyPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "score/user_only_posts.html"
    context_object_name = 'posts'

    paginate_by = 4

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(designer=user).order_by('-date_posted')

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserOnlyPostListView, self).get_context_data()
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))

        return context
```

Here is the template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
<td>{{ post.num_comments }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

My question:
Why am I receiving this error and how to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`comment_set` is the default `related_name` django gives to get all of the comments that point towards that particular instance of `Post`.

However, you have set `related_name="commented_posts"`, which means the default value of `comment_set` is overwritten, and you should use `post.commented_posts` rather than `post.comment_set`.

Note: It might be worth using a different related name as `post.commented_posts` is a bit confusing (as it's returning a set of Comments not Posts). A related name of `comments` would be better. That way you would use `post.comments`.

Answer (score 4):

instead of

```
return self.comment_set.all().count()
```

you have to use

```
 return self.commented_posts.all().count()
```

from your

```
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                         related_name="commented_posts")
```

if you delete related_name then you go with comment_set.